# Mysql remote connection works from command line/workbench but not from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple PHP script that tries to connecto to a remote database:

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect("remote-ip-address", "username", "password") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
```

When I run this, i get a not authorized error:

```
Access denied for user 'username'@'my-public-ip-address'
```

So my guess is that mysql is telling my that *username* is not allowed to connect from *my-public-ip-address*, right?. OK. Whats weird is that when i try to connect from command line or MySQL Workbench with this same credentials it works fine.

Why wouldn't PHP allow me to connect if i can from other mysql clients from the same host?

Comment: It's a MySQL error, so it's not PHP but MySQL hat does not let you connect. Your connecting IP-Address is always shown in the error message. MySQL will not reveal the actual reason why you are not allowed to connect, in that message. You should check if you are allowed to connect from that IP-Address. Maybe from command line you are not connecting from the same IP-Address. You could also revoke the rights for 'username' and compare the error from the command line to the PHP error.

Comment: I don't know, but I want to blame the problem on your use of the `mysql_*` functions instead of `mysqli_*`

Comment: Before you go down the road of using an obsolete API, one that was removed in PHP 7, use PDO at the very least. [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) has a lot of advice on what not to do.

Comment: At first i was using mysqli but since it wasn't working, i started testing different methods of connection, just in case. Even pdo throws the same error.

Comment: Ok, finally i found out what was wrong. I was using a password to connect and the server had passwordless access. Silly mistake.